# How to override the event handlers of built-in controls and its visibility in VSTO Outlook addin 2010

Tags: outlook

I have created a custom group with a toggle button in built-in 'TabAppointment' tab, where clicking on the button will open a new winform.

Only after proceeding with that form, 'Save&Close' button should be enabled in the appointment screen.

But iam not able to disbale the built-in controls, i have tried as like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
      <ribbon>
        <tabs>
          <tab idMso="TabAppointment">
            <group idMso ="GroupActions">
              <button idMso="SaveAndClose" getEnabled="GetEnabled"/>
            </group>
            <group id="GroupRBS" insertBeforeMso="GroupActions" label="RBS">
              <toggleButton id="btnBookRoom" label ="Add Room" supertip ="Room booking option for an appointment" imageMso="AddRoom" onAction="CallRBS" size="large" getEnabled="GetEnabled" />
            </group>
          </tab>
        </tabs>
      </ribbon>
    </customUI>
```

I have created 'GetEnabled' callback method in ribbon class, but it is firing only for custom group controls, cant we override builtin control attributes?

Iam able to hide builtin groups, but not able to  hide a particular builtin control inside the builtin group, is there any way to do this?

Pls help me for getting ny solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not change the Enabled state on built-in ribbon buttons. Only on the Custom ribbon buttons you add yourself.

But there are a couple solutions you could try:

1. Display your WinForm dialog [modally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure the user has to complete it before they can carry on
2. Handle the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItemClass.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitemclass.write.aspx) event. The [ItemEvents_10_WriteEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_writeeventhandler%28v=office.14%29.aspx) has a ref Cancel parameter which you can set to true to stop the Appointment being saved.

   `((ItemEvents_10_Event)appointmentItem).Write += AppointmentItem_Write;`